# Copy document library sharepoint 2003 include history

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I've got a sharepoint 2003 document library with 15000+ document. Now I want to archive it, for faster performance.

How can I copy the document library include content and history? I thought it was possible with stsadm, just like 2007. But that's not right.

Is there anyone with experience for keeping the version history?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You will need to develop an application to do this as it's not available out of the box. Good news is that it is possible to access past versions through the API.

I can't find much documentation for SharePoint 2003 online any more, but I don't think the version history functionality has changed much in 2007. Have a look at: [SPListItem.Versions Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx).